# "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" when counting the number of 1s in a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I've searched for this error but all the other errors relating to this TypeError seem to do with concatenation.

I'm just coding a simple app to replicate the Conway Game of Life, and part of the code is below:

```
def play_func():
    for row in two_dee_array:
        for col in row:
            n_neighbours = get_neighbours(two_dee_array, row, col)
            print(n_neighbours)


def get_neighbours(big_arr, row, col):
    sm_arr = big_arr[(row - 1):(row + 2), (col - 1):(col + 2)]
    b = 0
    i = row
    j = col
    for i in sm_arr:
        for j in i:
            if sm_arr[i, j] == 1:
                b += 1
    if sm_arr[row, col] == 1:
        b -= 1
    return b
```

with Pycharm spitting out:

```
  File "C:\Users\Joe\PycharmProjects\GoLv2\main.py", line 62, in play_func
    n_neighbours = get_neighbours(two_dee_array, row, col)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\PycharmProjects\GoLv2\main.py", line 68, in get_neighbours
    sm_arr = big_arr[(row - 1):(row + 2), (col - 1):(col + 2)]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I'm trying to learn Python so would appreciate your help and simple answers if possible that a new person would understand.

Cheers

Joe

Comment: Slice arguments have to be scalars, single numbers.  So if either `row` or `col` is an array (with more than 1 element), that will produce your error.

Comment: Assuming these arrays are numpy arrays, `row + 1` results in an array the size of `row` is that what you expect there?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand. I can't see how row or col can be an array? They're just indexing variables (a method of counting through the rows and cols), aren't they? They are numpy arrays, however I don't understand how row + 1 results in an array the size of row? It must be something fundamental that I'm missing I know, my apologies, beginner here.

Comment: If `two_dee_array` is 2d, the `row` (the iteration on it) is a 1d array, and `col`  is a single element of that array.   These `row` and `col` are  not indices, so can't be used to index `two_dee_array`.  I think you need to practice a bit more with simple Python iterations, starting with lists before moving on to numpy.